# PSQL character encoding/display strangeness

Tags: macos, postgresql, unicode, psql

I confess, this was stupid on my part, but I deleted some `.lproj` (*Mac*) files that I thought I didn't need. I thought I was careful to only remove those that really weren't necessary, but I suspect this is where the problem started.

When I go into `psql` and select from table.whatever I get `characters` like this at the top of the output (where the | and ___ lines would normally be displayed) :

```
<E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80> <E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2>
<94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94><80><E2><94>
```

Any suggestions as to how I might be able to fix this? I uninstalled and reinstall `pgsql`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I just found that if I do \pset pager off the problem goes away. I'd like to not have to do this. Just making note if it since it probably hints at the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS Terminal preferences, set the locale environment variables on startup, and restart your terminal. The problem should be gone.
[image]